# Use NFourierTransform to do a two dimensional fourier transformation and plot a picutre(mathematica)

Tags: mathematica-8

When I use the mathematica to calculate a numerical fourier transformation of two dimensional, there is no answer and even error reminding, just skip and finish without no result. Could you tell me what is wrong with it?

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Needs["FourierSeries`"]
f[t_, x_] := 
 UnitStep[1 - t] UnitStep[t + 1] UnitStep[1 - x] UnitStep[x + 1]
Plot3D[f[t, x], {t, -2, 2}, {x, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> All]
Plot3D[NFourierTransform[
  f[t, x], {t, x}, {omega, omega2}], {omega, -20, 20}, {omega2, -20, 
  20}, PlotRange -> All]
```